# Inquiry from Little's Law

Tags: network

Q = lambda * W

Where Q is the average number of packets in the queue, lambda is the average rate at which packets arrive in this link, and W is the average time that a packet spends in the queue.

Would it be sensible to use Little's Law to calculate the required buffer size at this link???

My approach: No, we can't calculate the buffer size from this equation.

Comment: The buffer size for what? Network device don't really have buffers the way you may understand it from buffering videos on the Internet. They may have small queues. For example, Cisco routers have small queues, and the trick is how to divide the queue size into the different queues you may need for QoS. You can also use something like RED to keep the queues from filling.

Comment: Uhmm I learned every router has a buffer.

Comment: Routers have queues. All have some small hardware queues, and some can also have some software queues, but they are relatively small. For example, the Cisco router queues total a few hundred bytes. On the other hand, your video buffer could be a couple of megabytes.

Comment: Queue/Buffer size will not be consistent across manufacturer or even device and then you throw in Hard Buffers and Soft Buffers it can be even more tricky. And since all packets would not necessarily be of equal size on any given network, I think your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Little's law tells you the *average* queue length for given average arrival and spent times, it doesn't tell you the *maximum* queue length.

To estimate a reasonable buffer size, you'd need the *variance* of arrival rates and spent times. With this you can calculate the probability of service for a packet and the opposite, packet loss.

If you want to make sure no packet can be lost, you need the *maximum* arrival rate and spent time to calculate a worst-case queue length, so no packet is ever lost.

What is your requirement?

Comment: There is no requirement. The problem is just ... "Would itbe sinsible to us Little's law .... ? If not, why?"

Comment: If this is an eductional question (which would be off-topic) you'll need to figure that out yourself. I've pretty much given you the answer above though.